# understanding the rules in a flex generator

Tags: compiler-construction, lex, flex-lexer

i am trying to work with a flex generator and how it works,the code below replaces the the sequence of symbols in a text file {number number} to {"d" ws "d"}, and it calculates the number of replacements

```
%{
   int count = 0;
%}
DIGIT [0-9]
%%
{DIGIT}{DIGIT} {count++; printf("d d");} 
%%
int main()
{
  yylex();
  printf( "\n#Report: %d changes made!", count);
  return 0;
}
int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
```

After submitting a file with the rules of the input file and compile flex lex.yy.c, received an executable file. The input to the executable file we submit the following data stream

```
====================test.in============================
wefwe
f
weferg54gfwsfwe
fwef
wefwefwf
wefewf21321dsfredf
sdf
===========================================================
```

the output obtained

============================test.out==================

```
wefwe
f
wefergd dgfwsfwe
fwef
wefwefwf
wefewfd dd d1dsfredf
sdf
#Report: 3 changes made!
```

========================================================

my question is that what if i want to
In the given text to replace the sequence of symbols {consonant  consonant} to {consonant «a» consonant} and calculate the number of replacements

Comment: I don't understand your question except that it appears to disagree with your title. Please try again.

Comment: I removed the "Adobe Flex" tag and replaced it w/ gnu-flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what concept you're stuck on.  Perhaps it's the idea of writing a character class to match consonants: let's consider "Y" to be a consonant for this question, and only match lower case letters.  Perhaps it's the question of how to access individual characters of the matched input: one way to do this is to declare `yytext` to be an `%array`.  At any rate, the code you want is something like this:

```
%{
    int count = 0;
    int consonantPatternCount = 0;
%}
%array
DIGIT [0-9]
CONSONANT [bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]
%%
{DIGIT}{DIGIT} {count++; printf("d d");}
{CONSONANT}{CONSONANT} { consonantPatternCount++; printf("%c a %c", yytext[0], yytext[1]);} 
%%
int main()
{
      yylex();
      printf( "\n#Report: %d changes made!", count);
      printf("\n#Report: %d consonant changes made", consonantPatternCount);
      return 0;
}
int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
```